# Disable jms listener in local environment

Tags: spring-boot, jms

How do i disable jms listener in my local environment? 
Since i am not connecting to MQ from the local enviroment, i donot want my console logs to get flooded with trying to connect MQ message. So i want to disable it locally.

I am using Spring boot and annotation based programming.I saw posts here suggesting to put autoStartup to false in properties but i cannot do that because i use spring boot.
I have commented all the code related to jms right now but how do we make jms listener run only in UAT or Prod server not on local server?

My code:

```
// @JmsListener(destination = "TOBUS", containerFactory = "defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
public void onMessage(final TextMessage message) throws JMSException {//some code here}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just add `spring.jms.listener.auto-startup=false` to your `application.properties` or even better in a specific `application-dev.properties` then when locally developing start the application with the `dev` profile so that it will disable the JMS listeners. Or start with `--spring.jms.listener.auto-startup=false` as a parameter either way will disable JMS. Basically you should do what the other posts tell you to. Your reasoning is a bit off you can do this because you are using Spring Boot not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks. I only saw posts about adding property in bean id tag not properties files so was mentioning that. Anyways thanks.I will try it

Comment: spring.jms.listener.auto-startup=false did not work.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot to automatically register the JMS stuff? You aren't registering your own `MessageListenerContainer`?

Comment: yes. i am using default one.

Answer (score 2):

The question is old but maybe can still interests someone.

There is at least two options to achieve this :

- Using profiles : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles
- Using conditional annotation : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration.condition-annotations

Is is not tell if this is already the case but first I would set the listening method in a separate bean. Appart from the fact that the proposed solutions work only with this kind of code organisation, it is better in term of Separation of Concerns/Responsability and then easier for implementing unit tests, the former implies the latter.

- Using profiles : make your listener bean available only if a 'local' profile is not active.

```
    @Profile("!local")
    @Component
    public class MyBeanListener {
    
        @JmsListener(destination = "TOBUS", containerFactory = "defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
        public void onMessage(final TextMessage message) throws JMSException {//some code here}
    
    }
```

Then start your application with the profile 'local' defines.

- Using conditional annotation : make your listener bean available unless a certain property is defined

```
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "jms.listener.enable", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    @Component
    public class MyBeanListener {
    
        @JmsListener(destination = "TOBUS", containerFactory = "defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
        public void onMessage(final TextMessage message) throws JMSException {//some code here}
        
    }
```

Then define a property "jms.listener.enable=false" only for your local environment (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)

NB : These annotations work at beans definition level (on @Configuration classes or on @Bean method factory), then setting them on the @JmsListener annotated method will have not effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
spring.jms.listener.auto-startup=false
```

This worked for me