# how to disable springboot solace jms consumer

Tags: spring-boot, solace, solace-mq

I am using soalce consumer with Spring boot autoconfig. Using below configurations.

```
solace.jms.msgVpn=****
solace.jms.clientUsername=****
solace.jms.clientPassword=****
solace.jms.clientName=****
```

But I would like to disable consumer in some environments. @ConditionalOnProperty I will not be able to use. Is there property provided by solace out of the box to disable it?

Thanks

Comment: Please try the answers here since you're using JMS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220223/disable-jms-listener-in-local-environment